# Slow shutdown due to modemmanager and .. nm-dispatcher.action?

Tags: 11.10, networking, shutdown

My ubuntu is slow to shutdown, and the culprits seem to be `modemmanager` and something called `nm-dispatcher.action`.

On shutdown I get a message on the terminal saying something like "asking all remaining processes to terminate" and then there is a ~5 second delay, before unresponsive processes are forcibly killed.

One of them was modem-manager, and I don't have a modem so I fixed that one with simply `sudo apt-get remove modemmanager` and there doesn't appear to be any side effects.

The other one is something like "nm-dispatcher.action: Caught signal 15, shutting down. ..." which I was able to fix by removing `network-manager` and `network-manager-gnome`.  But then, obviously, I don't get the network manager icons and stuff which I need in gnome-shell.  I have tried `wicd` as a replacement, but it is not working to my liking.

So how can I prevent those processes from hanging during shutdown?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the bug report on, no sign of a fix.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/869635

The report does mention an edit one can make to /etc/init/network-manager.conf, ie. add as shown

```
stop on runlevel [06]
```

I believe adding the line was effective here though myself use Wicd & have removed network-manager. YMMV, if trying & it causes issues then remove the added line

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried the ideas mentioned above (because I wasn't aware of them at the time), but I did try the fix mentioned at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netbase/+bug/903825 which worked well for me. Now Oneiric shuts down much faster than before.