# How to troubleshoot slow shutdown?

Tags: shutdown

When I shutdown my computer there is some annoying delay, it takes about 5-10 seconds in 13.10 when in the previous version it was almost instantaneous.

During shutdown I press escape to cancel the splash screen and can see that a big part of the delay is after "Asking all remaining process to terminate...", and then there is "Killing all remaining processes".  I have filmed the process with my video camera to check which processes had to be killed, but they didn't chat anything to the terminal.

I previously had this same issue in 11.10, and I resolved it as answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/87576/21350), however this did not work for me in 13.10.

How to identify the cause of delays in the shutdown process, and fix them?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Turn on reporting for misbehaving applications:

1. Open `/etc/init.d/sendsigs` in your favourite text editor, with root privileges (e.g `sudo vi /etc/init.d/sendsigs` or `gksu /etc/init.d/sendsigs`). Search for the line `#report_unkillable` and uncomment it (i.e. remove the `#` tag). Save the file.
2. Make sure that apport is enabled: Edit the file `/etc/default/apport` so it reads `enabled=1`. (If it was `enabled=0` then reboot, so apport can start.)
3. Shutdown.
4. Upon the next boot `apport` should come up with a message telling you that there was some kind of problem with a program. That is the one causing the delay. And there should be a crash report in `/var/crash` . (If apport doesn't report the name, then just look in the crash file, in the end of the file there will be something like `Title: MISBEHAVING_PROGRAMNAME does not terminate at computer shutdown`)

Comment: I get a report about `/sbin/initctl` (initctl does not terminate at computer shutdown)

Comment: Here is a bug report (not really usefully informational, but it does show that at least one other person has had this problem and reported it): https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart/+bug/1261177

Comment: That is my bug report  :)

Comment: no `/etc/init.d//sendsigs` in ubuntu 20.04 ;c

Answer (score -1):

Is the shutdown always slow or can it vary? If the latter is the case, what did you do before shutting down? Did you do something that took a lot of disk-writes that perhaps need to end first before all processes can be terminated?

you could save a list of all processes before shutting down as per:

ps -A > processes.txt

before you shutdown.

You could take a look at any errors that might have occurred after restart as per:

dmesg |tail

Hope this helps

Frank

Comment: it is slow everytime, even on a fresh boot

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried this? Open terminal and type

```
sudo shutdown now
```

This might help.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't give me any more information than I already saw by checking the output with a video camera

Comment: Why would this make any difference whatsoever?