# initctl does not terminate at computer shutdown

Tags: shutdown, restart

I have a fresh install of 13.10 on an ASUS Zenbook UX31E.  Every shutdown there is a hang, and with the help of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/390185/21350) I think I have identified the cause to be `/sbin/initctl` which does not terminate at shutdown (it is killed after several seconds delay).

How can I configure `initctl` to exit cleanly when it is asked?

Attached is the auto-generated file in `/var/crash/_sbin_initctl.0.crash`

```
ProblemType: Bug
Date: Sun Dec 15 17:16:40 2013
ExecutablePath: /sbin/initctl
ExecutableTimestamp: 1381333523
InitctlList:
 avahi-cups-reload stop/waiting
 avahi-daemon start/running, process 710
 mountall-net stop/waiting
 mountnfs-bootclean.sh start/running
 passwd stop/waiting
 rc start/running, process 5044
 rsyslog stop/waiting
 startpar-bridge stop/waiting
 tty4 stop/waiting
 udev stop/waiting
 upstart-udev-bridge stop/waiting
 ureadahead-other stop/waiting
 whoopsie stop/waiting
 winbind stop/waiting
 apport stop/waiting
 console-setup stop/waiting
 hwclock-save stop/waiting
 irqbalance stop/waiting
 plymouth-log stop/waiting
 systemd-logind start/running, process 611
 tty5 stop/waiting
 failsafe stop/waiting
 hybrid-gfx stop/waiting
 modemmanager stop/waiting
 mountall.sh start/running
 rfkill-store stop/waiting
 atd stop/waiting
 dbus start/running, process 570
 failsafe-x stop/waiting
 mounted-var stop/waiting
 plymouth start/running, process 5165
 resolvconf stop/waiting
 udev-fallback-graphics stop/waiting
 checkroot.sh start/running
 control-alt-delete stop/waiting
 hwclock stop/waiting
 mounted-proc stop/waiting
 network-manager stop/waiting
 alsa-store stop/waiting
 cups-browsed stop/waiting
 setvtrgb stop/waiting
 shutdown stop/waiting
 alsa-restore stop/waiting
 cron stop/waiting
 gdm stop/waiting
 lightdm stop/waiting
 mountall stop/waiting
 mounted-debugfs stop/waiting
 mountkernfs.sh start/running
 binfmt-support stop/waiting
 console stop/waiting
 mounted-run stop/waiting
 acpid stop/waiting
 bluetooth start/running, process 599
 checkfs.sh start/running
 checkroot-bootclean.sh start/running
 kmod stop/waiting
 mountnfs.sh start/running
 plymouth-stop stop/waiting
 rcS stop/waiting
 ufw start/running
 wait-for-state stop/waiting
 bootmisc.sh start/running
 flush-early-job-log stop/waiting
 friendly-recovery stop/waiting
 rc-sysinit stop/waiting
 cups stop/waiting
 pulseaudio stop/waiting
 upstart-socket-bridge stop/waiting
 anacron stop/waiting
 mountdevsubfs.sh start/running
 tty2 stop/waiting
 udevtrigger stop/waiting
 upstart-file-bridge stop/waiting
 container-detect stop/waiting
 mounted-dev stop/waiting
 mtab.sh start/running
 tty3 stop/waiting
 udev-finish stop/waiting
 alsa-state stop/waiting
 hostname stop/waiting
 mountall-reboot stop/waiting
 mountall-shell stop/waiting
 mounted-tmp stop/waiting
 network-interface (lo) start/running
 network-interface (wlan0) start/running
 plymouth-ready (started) start/running, process 5182
 plymouth-splash stop/waiting
 plymouth-upstart-bridge stop/waiting
 tty1 stop/waiting
 udevmonitor stop/waiting
 dmesg stop/waiting
 mountall-bootclean.sh start/running
 network-interface-security (network-interface/wlan0) start/running
 network-interface-security (network-interface/lo) start/running
 network-interface-security (networking) start/running
 networking start/running
 procps stop/waiting
 rfkill-restore stop/waiting
 tty6 stop/waiting
 console-font stop/waiting
 network-interface-container stop/waiting
 ureadahead stop/waiting
OmitPids: 1360 1112 710 5044 5047 611 570 869 1079 599 710 5044 611 570 5165 599 5182
ProcCmdline: initctl emit plymouth-ready
ProcCwd: /
ProcEnviron:
 TERM=linux
 PATH=(custom, no user)
ProcMaps:
 7fe15af99000-7fe15afb0000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 1839046                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.17.so
 7fe15afb0000-7fe15b1b0000 ---p 00017000 08:02 1839046                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.17.so
 7fe15b1b0000-7fe15b1b1000 r--p 00017000 08:02 1839046                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.17.so
 7fe15b1b1000-7fe15b1b2000 rw-p 00018000 08:02 1839046                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.17.so
 7fe15b1b2000-7fe15b1b6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7fe15b1b6000-7fe15b1bd000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 1839054                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.17.so
 7fe15b1bd000-7fe15b3bc000 ---p 00007000 08:02 1839054                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.17.so
 7fe15b3bc000-7fe15b3bd000 r--p 00006000 08:02 1839054                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.17.so
 7fe15b3bd000-7fe15b3be000 rw-p 00007000 08:02 1839054                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.17.so
 7fe15b3be000-7fe15b57b000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 1838931                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
 7fe15b57b000-7fe15b77b000 ---p 001bd000 08:02 1838931                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
 7fe15b77b000-7fe15b77f000 r--p 001bd000 08:02 1838931                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
 7fe15b77f000-7fe15b781000 rw-p 001c1000 08:02 1838931                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
 7fe15b781000-7fe15b786000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7fe15b786000-7fe15b7ca000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 1838943                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3.7.4
 7fe15b7ca000-7fe15b9c9000 ---p 00044000 08:02 1838943                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3.7.4
 7fe15b9c9000-7fe15b9ca000 r--p 00043000 08:02 1838943                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3.7.4
 7fe15b9ca000-7fe15b9cb000 rw-p 00044000 08:02 1838943                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3.7.4
 7fe15b9cb000-7fe15b9d3000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 1838994                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnih-dbus.so.1.0.0
 7fe15b9d3000-7fe15bbd3000 ---p 00008000 08:02 1838994                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnih-dbus.so.1.0.0
 7fe15bbd3000-7fe15bbd4000 r--p 00008000 08:02 1838994                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnih-dbus.so.1.0.0
 7fe15bbd4000-7fe15bbd5000 rw-p 00009000 08:02 1838994                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnih-dbus.so.1.0.0
 7fe15bbd5000-7fe15bbeb000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 1838996                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnih.so.1.0.0
 7fe15bbeb000-7fe15bdeb000 ---p 00016000 08:02 1838996                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnih.so.1.0.0
 7fe15bdeb000-7fe15bdec000 r--p 00016000 08:02 1838996                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnih.so.1.0.0
 7fe15bdec000-7fe15bded000 rw-p 00017000 08:02 1838996                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnih.so.1.0.0
 7fe15bded000-7fe15be10000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 1838907                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so
 7fe15bfe9000-7fe15bfee000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7fe15c00d000-7fe15c00f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7fe15c00f000-7fe15c010000 r--p 00022000 08:02 1838907                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so
 7fe15c010000-7fe15c012000 rw-p 00023000 08:02 1838907                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so
 7fe15c012000-7fe15c03e000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 3014717                    /sbin/initctl
 7fe15c23d000-7fe15c23f000 r--p 0002b000 08:02 3014717                    /sbin/initctl
 7fe15c23f000-7fe15c240000 rw-p 0002d000 08:02 3014717                    /sbin/initctl
 7fe15c68d000-7fe15c6ae000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
 7fffddbf4000-7fffddc15000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
 7fffddcad000-7fffddcaf000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
 ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
ProcStatus:
 Name:  initctl
 State: S (sleeping)
 Tgid:  5185
 Pid:   5185
 PPid:  5182
 TracerPid: 0
 Uid:   0   0   0   0
 Gid:   0   0   0   0
 FDSize:    64
 Groups:    0 
 VmPeak:       15316 kB
 VmSize:       15316 kB
 VmLck:        0 kB
 VmPin:        0 kB
 VmHWM:     1060 kB
 VmRSS:     1060 kB
 VmData:         204 kB
 VmStk:      136 kB
 VmExe:      176 kB
 VmLib:     2432 kB
 VmPTE:       52 kB
 VmSwap:           0 kB
 Threads:   1
 SigQ:  0/30476
 SigPnd:    0000000000000000
 ShdPnd:    0000000000000000
 SigBlk:    0000000000000000
 SigIgn:    0000000000000000
 SigCgt:    0000000180000000
 CapInh:    0000000000000000
 CapPrm:    0000001fffffffff
 CapEff:    0000001fffffffff
 CapBnd:    0000001fffffffff
 Seccomp:   0
 Cpus_allowed:  ffff
 Cpus_allowed_list: 0-15
 Mems_allowed:  00000000,00000001
 Mems_allowed_list: 0
 voluntary_ctxt_switches:   55
 nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches:    1
Processes:
 USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
 root         1  0.0  0.0  27300  3084 ?        Ss   15:34   0:01 /sbin/init
 root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [kthreadd]
 root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [ksoftirqd/0]
 root         5  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   15:34   0:00 [kworker/0:0H]
 root         7  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [migration/0]
 root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [rcu_bh]
 root         9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [rcuob/0]
 root        10  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [rcuob/1]
 root        11  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [rcuob/2]
 root        12  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [rcuob/3]
 root        13  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [rcuob/4]
 root        14  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [rcuob/5]
 root        15  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [rcuob/6]
 root        16  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [rcuob/7]
 root        17  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [rcuob/8]
 root        18  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [rcuob/9]
 root        19  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [rcuob/10]
 root        20  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [rcuob/11]
 root        21  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [rcuob/12]
 root        22  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [rcuob/13]
 root        23  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [rcuob/14]
 root        24  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [rcuob/15]
 root        25  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:03 [rcu_sched]
 root        26  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [rcuos/0]
 root        27  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:01 [rcuos/1]
 root        28  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [rcuos/2]
 root        29  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [rcuos/3]
 root        30  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [rcuos/4]
 root        31  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [rcuos/5]
 root        32  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [rcuos/6]
 root        33  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [rcuos/7]
 root        34  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [rcuos/8]
 root        35  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [rcuos/9]
 root        36  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [rcuos/10]
 root        37  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [rcuos/11]
 root        38  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [rcuos/12]
 root        39  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [rcuos/13]
 root        40  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [rcuos/14]
 root        41  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [rcuos/15]
 root        42  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [watchdog/0]
 root        43  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [watchdog/1]
 root        44  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [migration/1]
 root        45  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [ksoftirqd/1]
 root        47  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   15:34   0:00 [kworker/1:0H]
 root        48  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [watchdog/2]
 root        49  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [migration/2]
 root        50  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [ksoftirqd/2]
 root        52  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   15:34   0:00 [kworker/2:0H]
 root        53  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [watchdog/3]
 root        54  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [migration/3]
 root        55  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [ksoftirqd/3]
 root        56  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [kworker/3:0]
 root        57  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   15:34   0:00 [kworker/3:0H]
 root        58  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   15:34   0:00 [khelper]
 root        59  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [kdevtmpfs]
 root        60  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   15:34   0:00 [netns]
 root        61  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   15:34   0:00 [writeback]
 root        62  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   15:34   0:00 [kintegrityd]
 root        63  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   15:34   0:00 [bioset]
 root        64  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   15:34   0:04 [kworker/u33:0]
 root        65  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   15:34   0:00 [kblockd]
 root        66  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   15:34   0:00 [ata_sff]
 root        67  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [khubd]
 root        68  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   15:34   0:00 [md]
 root        69  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   15:34   0:00 [devfreq_wq]
 root        70  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:01 [kworker/1:1]
 root        72  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [khungtaskd]
 root        73  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [kswapd0]
 root        74  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   15:34   0:00 [ksmd]
 root        75  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   15:34   0:00 [khugepaged]
 root        76  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [fsnotify_mark]
 root        77  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [ecryptfs-kthrea]
 root        78  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   15:34   0:00 [crypto]
 root        90  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   15:34   0:00 [kthrotld]
 root        93  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:02 [kworker/3:1]
 root       115  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   15:34   0:00 [deferwq]
 root       116  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   15:34   0:00 [charger_manager]
 root       117  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [kworker/2:1]
 root       168  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [scsi_eh_0]
 root       169  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [scsi_eh_1]
 root       170  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [scsi_eh_2]
 root       171  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [scsi_eh_3]
 root       172  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [scsi_eh_4]
 root       173  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [scsi_eh_5]
 root       179  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:04 [kworker/u32:7]
 root       189  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [jbd2/sda2-8]
 root       190  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   15:34   0:00 [ext4-rsv-conver]
 root       191  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   15:34   0:00 [ext4-unrsv-conv]
 root       379  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   15:34   0:00 [cfg80211]
 root       380  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:34   0:00 [irq/51-mei_me]
 root       416  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:35   0:00 [scsi_eh_6]
 root       421  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:35   0:00 [rts5139-control]
 root       422  0.2  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:35   0:13 [rts5139-polling]
 root       426  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   15:35   0:00 [kpsmoused]
 root       463  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   15:35   0:00 [led_workqueue]
 root       478  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   15:35   0:00 [hci0]
 root       479  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   15:35   0:00 [hci0]
 root       507  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   15:35   0:00 [kvm-irqfd-clean]
 root       540  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   15:35   0:00 [hd-audio0]
 102        570  0.0  0.0  31528  2448 ?        Ss   15:35   0:02 dbus-daemon --system --fork
 root       599  0.0  0.0  19388  2120 ?        Ss   15:35   0:00 /usr/sbin/bluetoothd
 root       611  0.0  0.0  37152  1784 ?        Ss   15:35   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-logind
 root       623  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   15:35   0:00 [krfcommd]
 avahi      710  0.0  0.0  32352  1808 ?        S    15:35   0:00 avahi-daemon: running [wim-zenbook.local]
 avahi      713  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    15:35   0:00 [avahi-daemon] <defunct>
 root       813  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:35   0:02 [kworker/2:2]
 root      1112  0.0  0.0  32444  2556 ?        Ss   15:35   0:00 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -B -P /run/sendsigs.omit.d/wpasupplicant.pid -u -s -O /var/run/wpa_supplicant
 root      1136  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:35   0:00 [kauditd]
 root      1732  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:59   0:02 [kworker/u32:0]
 root      4609  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:29   0:02 [kworker/1:2]
 root      4690  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:36   0:02 [kworker/0:0]
 root      4749  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:51   0:00 [kworker/0:2]
 root      4820  0.2  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   16:59   0:02 [kworker/u33:2]
 root      4968  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    17:10   0:00 [kworker/u32:1]
 root      5044  0.0  0.0   4440   796 ?        Ss   17:16   0:00 /bin/sh /etc/init.d/rc 0
 root      5108  0.0  0.0   4440   784 ?        S    17:16   0:00 /bin/sh /etc/rc0.d/S20sendsigs stop
 root      5135  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    17:16   0:00 [kworker/3:2]
 root      5141  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    17:16   0:00 [kworker/3:3]
 root      5142  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    17:16   0:00 [kworker/3:4]
 root      5165  1.0  0.4 121780 18460 ?        S    17:16   0:00 @sbin/plymouthd --mode=shutdown
 root      5182  0.0  0.0   4440   620 ?        Ss   17:16   0:00 /bin/sh -e /proc/self/fd/9
 root      5185  0.0  0.0  15316  1060 ?        S    17:16   0:00 initctl emit plymouth-ready
 root      5246  0.0  0.3  64680 14844 ?        S    17:16   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/share/apport/unkillable_shutdown -o 1360 -o 1112 -o 710 -o 5044 -o 5047 -o 611 -o 570 -o 869 -o 1079 -o 599 -o 710 -o 5044 -o 611 -o 570 -o 5165 -o 599 -o 5182
 root      5247  0.0  0.0  15568  1168 ?        R    17:16   0:00 ps aux
Tags: shutdown-hang
Title: initctl does not terminate at computer shutdown
```

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same issue with my Zenbook UX31E.

I also have a fresh install of 13.10, with a few tweaks that are described there:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AsusZenbook

---

I've just applied the workaround in the bug description here:   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sysvinit/+bug/1212142

I edited `/etc/rc0.d/S20sendsigs`, changing the `for seq in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10; do` to `for seq in 1 ; do`.

That doesn't make initctl exit cleanly, but it avoids vainly waiting 10 seconds for the process to end and the shutdown is fast again.