# 13.10 Shutdown/Restart issue

Tags: 13.10, shutdown, restart

I have a clean install of 13.10 using the 3.12 kernel. When I shutdown or restart the process hangs. I press a key and I see:

```
**Killing all remaining processes .......      [fail]** (fail is in red)
```

This is followed by more info (sometime referring to `nmdispatcher` or `modem` and always ends:

```
mount:/ is busy

will now restart (or halt as the case may be)
```

Then nothing else happens the process hangs there, power on my PC (Dell 5150 desktop) remains on and I need to do a "hard reset" to turn my PC off.

I have seen relatively similar problems but none match mine exactly, I have attempted using:

```
sudo shutdown -P now
```

or

```
sudo shutdown -H now
```

But the results are the same.

I am concerned that this unclean shutdown may cause problems and I would like to know how to solve the problem.  Can anybody help me?  I am not too experienced with Ubuntu and I'm stuck...  thanks

Comment: Please see the answer to [this question](http://askubuntu.com/a/390185/221281) on how to troubleshoot slow shutdowns. Then report back what is that misbehaving application which won't terminate.

Comment: Ok, followed the procedures and reading through the crash report I see **pci_devices does not terminate at computer shutdown**

Comment: That looks like hardware/kernel related. Have you tried [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/127022/221281) ?

Comment: Yes I tried the **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"** part of that solution, I don't have an NVIDIA card so didn't follow the rest of it: no change.  I even did some reading around and thought it might be a kernel issue so I only updated to the 3.12 kernel yesterday before posting but still made no difference.

Comment: @welfare GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force" and then `sudo update-grub` did not worked for me !

Answer (score 0):

You probably have tried this one but, since you haven't mentioned that - try `sudo reboot`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but, yes when I tried it I got the same result.