# Endless "Wait-for-state stop-waiting" when shutdown

Tags: 14.04, shutdown

### Problem description

When I shutdown my pc with:

- `sudo shutdown -v now`
- `sudo reboot`
- or a normal shutdown

I'm getting an endless shutdown.
By pressing `F1` or `Esc` I can get black console window with line

```
Wait-for-state stop/waiting
```

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Delete</kbd> some lines appear, but I can't see error there.
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> enables a console, but I can't type there while shutting down.

---

### Additional information

Problem appeared after installation of Canon LBP6000 printer's driver. 
I used this [instruction](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CanonCaptDrv190).
Also I done some neccesary things to make printer work: `chmod 777 /dev/usb/lp0`

---

### What I did to solve this problem (but still no luck)

I completed suggestions from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/369613/how-to-troubleshoot-slow-shutdown).
Result of this and my system information are [here](https://imgur.com/gallery/lDE6m/).

Comment: You can answer your own question next time to add the answer to your own question.  You should however include steps and such from linked posts to make sure the solutions are kept if a link dies, though.

Comment: Who disliked this? This is a well made post. Or maybe it's just the review stuff again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ran into the same problem with ubuntu 14.04 and canon printer drivers. Had to remove everything i installed. 
Only after running one of these solved shutdown/restart problem:

```
sudo apt-get purge libpopt0:i386
sudo update-rc.d -f ccpd remove
# commented out in /etc/ccpd.conf: section <Printer> completely and inside <Ports>
sudo apt-get purge cups cups-daemon cups-server-common
sudo apt-get purge portreserve
```

I'm pretty sure that `sudo update-rc.d -f ccpd remove` is the fix, but i won't install canon drivers ever again :)

PS: please note that removing ccpd from upstart job will not start printing stuff automatically.

Comment: Seems like problem in `ccpd` only. The only workaround here is to start ccpd by hands on system start and disable before shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the wait-for-state/stop-waiting on shutdown of a 14.04 live CD session on a specific machine, Packard Bell PEW92, single core Celeron 64bit architecture.
Below you will find the readout.

I do not install anything though I remove remote login service plus uninstall amazon regardless what machine I utilize.

I toggle the same DVD with ubuntu 14.04 live CD ISO between a variety of machines.
The Packard Bell is the only machine where this happens.
However, a full 14.04 install with all updates (from a while ago) on an 8GB Sandisk SSD salvaged from a Motorola mediabox does not feature this issue (same purge plus uninstall performed).

My conclusion is this issue is hardware specific, differs per case.
Other then a purge of what triggers the event, this issue is not preventable since this event is triggered by software that doesn't function in full compatibility with the specific hardware utilized at the moment the event is triggered.

```
*Stoppin rsync deamon rsync [ok]
*speech-dispatcher disabled; edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
*Asking all remaining processes to terminate... [ok]
*All processes ended within 1 seconds... [ok]
ModemManager[1267]: <info> Caught signal, shutting down...

ModemManager[1267]: <info> ModemManager is shut down

*Unmounting temporary filesystems... [ok]
*Deactivating swap... [ok]
*Stopping early crypto disks [ok]
```

After a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>

```
[[ 4967.912031] ata2.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x10000 action 0xe frozen

[ 4967.912071] ata2.00: irq_stat 0x00400003, PHY RDY changed

[ 4967.912095] ata2: SError: { PHYRdyChg }

[ 4967.912121] ata2.00: cmd a0/00:00:00:08:00/00:00:00:00:00:/a0 tag 28 pio 16392 in

[ 4967.912121]          Get event status notification 4a 01 00 00 10 00 00 00 08
                        00res 50/00:03:00:08:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus
                        error)
[ 4967.912222] ata2.00: status: { DRDY }
```

After another <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>

```
* Starting Waiting for state [ok]
* Starting Waiting for state [fail]

start: Job failed to start
* Stopping Waiting for state [ok]
* Asking all remaining processes to terminate... [ok]
* All processes ended within 1 seconds... [ok]
* Deactivating swap... [ok]
* Stopping early crypto disks... [ok]
```