# Reduce shutdown time?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, shutdown, apport, tlp

How can I reduce shutdown time?

The guest session takes only 1 second, but my session take about 10 seconds. I checked the first [answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/369613/how-to-troubleshoot-slow-shutdown), but `apport` doesn't show any thing is their any way to know where is the problem?

At the beginning it takes 2 seconds, after installing `TLP` it takes about 10 seconds but I think it's not caused by `TLP` because I installed it before on ubuntu `14.04` with no problems. Now I'm using `16.04`.

Comment: When the shutdown is stalled at the Splash screen, sometimes when really in a hurry I press ESC, and there are messages about what's holding the shutdown sequence and I don recall exactly but hitting maybe ESC again will give a seconds value for shutdown in average 10 secs in my case.  If this works Maybe someone can confirm the exact keybindings.

Comment: @user3005629 thanks for replaying, i think it's caused by tlp i remove it works fine now.